# How to draw graph with dodged position?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am an R novice. I will try to be as brief and simple as possible. Currently, I am trying to connect points between two conditions based on another condition all over a single discrete x-axis.

Below is some test data and my attempt to plot some data.

```
set.seed(42)

# Test case data
mydf1 <- tibble(
  xx = rep('myLabel', 8),
  yy = rnorm(8),
  grp = rep(c(1, 2), each = 4),
  cond = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), length.out = 8)
)

ggplot(mydf1, aes(x = xx, y = yy, col = factor(grp))) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + 
  geom_path(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), aes(group = cond), col = "black") +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Test Case for geom_path and position_dodge")
```

[image]

From what I can tell, it seems that position_dodge is applied after the draw. Is there a way to change this behavior? or to achieve the overall goal of connecting these points in this type of way?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: details.

EDIT2:

I would like to capture a before and after relationship between `grp` based on 4 conditions in one big main conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want this.

```
set.seed(42)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydf1, aes(x = grp, y = yy, col = factor(grp))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path(aes(group = cond), col = "black") +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Test Case for geom_path and position_dodge") +
  xlim(c(.5, 2.5)) +
  labs(color = "Group", x = "myLabel", y = "yy") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is very close! How would you remove x-ticks and move "myLabel" to the x-axis?

Comment: *Note:* I have improved slightly the code, so if your groups appear to close for your taste you can play around with the `xlim(.)`, e.g. `xlim(c(.7, 2.3))`.

Answer (score 2):

You could plot a categorical x axis.

```
ggplot(mydf1, aes(x = cond, y = yy, col = factor(grp))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_path(aes(group = cond), col = "black") +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Test Case for categorical X-axis")
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you need comparison across multiple categorical dimensions mapped to the x axis, you can try facets.

```
 ggplot(mydf1, aes(x = cond, y = yy, col = factor(grp))) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_path(aes(group = cond), col = "black") +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Test Case for Categorical X-axis and Facets") +
  facet_wrap(~cond)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I should've stated this in the main post. I want to capture a before and after relationship between `grp` based on 4 conditions in one big main condition. I will add this as an edit.